# Is a CONSTANT a Super Global?

Tags: php, global-variables, constants

Can constants be used as a SuperGlobal?

i.e. in my index.php i define a certain lang:

```
define('USER_SYSTEM_LANG', $UserLang);
```

Can i use the `USER_SYSTEM_LANG` throughout my MVC application?

Or should it take care of these type of variables a different way?

Comment: No it is not a super global. You can use it anywhere after you have defined it though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php):

> Like superglobals, the scope of a constant is global. You can access constants anywhere in your script without regard to scope.

Comment: if the $UserLang differs per visitor, is it wise to set it via a CONSTANT, or is it better to store it in the session? $_SESSION['UserLang'].

Comment: You can set the value of the constant from the session variable or any other source you want. Constant values do not need to be defined before runtime or hard-coded in. They can be assigned dynamically.

Comment: Everything affects performance. It just won't affect performance in a way that you'll notice.